# How to Convert Dictionary of Columns into Dictionary of Rows?

Tags: python, dictionary

If this is a duplicate, let me know - but I tried finding an answer on Stack but couldn't.

Hi, I'm not sure if this requires a recursive function - I've had a think but I'm not sure how best to go about converting this dictionary.

Essentially I've gotten some CSV data and have converted into the following dictionary of columns:

```py
{
    'column1': [Row1Col1Data, Row2Col1Data],
    'column2': [Row1Col2Data, Row2Col2Data],
    'column3': [Row1Col3Data, Row2Col3Data]
}
```

and I want to convert it into this:

```py
{
    'row1':{
            'column1': Row1Col1Data,
            'column2': Row1Col2Data
           },
    'row2':{
            'column1': Row2Col1Data,
            'column2': Row2Col2Data
           }
}
```

Essentially to swap the dictionary items from columns to rows. Can somebody help, or link to a solution because I've struggled to find one.

When I refer to `'row1'` and `'row2'` in my second example, these can just be an integer counting up (e.g. 1, 2, 3) they don't have to be anything specific - they just represent each row.

Here's what I've tried already (with data being what the first code snippet looks like):

```py
new_data = {}

for column in data:
    count = 1
    for data_point in column:
        if key not in new_data:
            new_data[str(count)] = {}

        new_data[str(count)][column] = data_point
        count += 1
```

But it doesn't work correctly, It seems to iterate over each letter of the data key names. Can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: just read csv file according to your 2nd scheme from the very start

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks, that's what I ended up doing and posted it in my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have `pandas` available:

```
{ ('row%d' % (1+i)) : {j : coldata[j][i] for j in coldata.keys()} for i in range(len(coldata['column1'])) }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `pandas` librarie and `dataframe.transpose()` :

```
import pandas as pd

your_dict = {
    "column1": ["Row1Col1Data", "Row2Col1Data"],
    "column2": ["Row1Col2Data", "Row2Col2Data"],
    "column3": ["Row1Col3Data", "Row2Col3Data"],
}

output_dict = pd.DataFrame(your_dict).transpose().to_dict()
```

Result :

```
{
    0: {
        "column1": "Row1Col1Data",
        "column2": "Row1Col2Data",
        "column3": "Row1Col3Data",
    },
    1: {
        "column1": "Row2Col1Data",
        "column2": "Row2Col2Data",
        "column3": "Row2Col3Data",
    },
}
```

There could be better to way to do it I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of rows is consistent throughout the csv file (your data is a matrix), then you can do this without any third party libraries:

```
data = {
    "column1": ["Row1Col1Data", "Row2Col1Data"],
    "column2": ["Row1Col2Data", "Row2Col2Data"],
    "column3": ["Row1Col3Data", "Row2Col3Data"],
}

number_rows = len(data["column1"]) 
number_columns = len(data.keys())
new_data = {"row" + str(i + 1): {"column" + str(j + 1) : list(data.values())[j][i] for j in range(number_columns)} for i in range(number_rows)}}
```

This is the result:

```
>>> new_data
{
'row1': {'column1': 'Row1Col1Data',
          'column2': 'Row1Col2Data',
          'column3': 'Row1Col3Data'},
 'row2': {'column1': 'Row2Col1Data',
          'column2': 'Row2Col2Data',
          'column3': 'Row2Col3Data'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla Python:

```
col_data = {
    'col1': ['r1c1', 'r2c1'],
    'col2': ['r1c2', 'r2c2'],
    'col3': ['r1c3', 'r2c3'],
}

# Safety check in case columns don't have the same length
col_len = min(len(col) for col in col_data.values())

row_data = {f'row{i+1}': [val[i] for val in col_data.values()]
             for i in range(col_len)}
```

Resulting value of `row_data`:

```
{
    'row1': ['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3'],
    'row2': ['r2c1', 'r2c2', 'r2c3']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you exactly what you asked for in one line using list comprehension.

```
def transpose(input_dict):

output_dict = {
    f"row{j+1}": {
        f"column{i+1}": values[1][j] for i, values in enumerate(input_dict.items())
    }
    for j in range(len(next(iter(input_dict.values()))))
}

return output_dict
```